# Reconstructing triangles given side lengths and centroid

Tags: reference-request, triangles

Suppose that the centroid of an unknown triangle $ABC$ is $(0,0)$.
Suppose also that 3 lengths $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are given, where $\alpha$ is the length of $BC$, $\beta$ is the length of $AC$, and $\gamma$ is the length of $AB$.

*Question:* How do I find all $ABC$ given this information?

I assume that $ABC$ is unique up to rotation and "flipping". (Sorry, I am not a geometer.) I am particular interested in the Cartesian coordinates of $A,B,C$. Reference would be most welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Without loss of generality, the side of the triangle *below* the centroid is parallel to the $x$-axis.  Since all $3$ sides are known, the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) gives you all $3$ angles.  Then, since the inner triangle formed by a median is known via *side-angle-side*, the length of the median is known.  This implies (again using the Law of Cosines) that the $6$ vertex angles formed by the medians are all known.  ...see next comment

Comment: Further, by the [Centroid of a Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_triangle) you know the distance from the centroid (i.e. $(0,0)$) to each vertex.  This implies that you know the (directional angle + length) of the centroid to each vertex.  This is **game over**.

Comment: @user2661923 thanks for this. As stated, Ii am not a geometer. I am interested in the Cartesian coordinates of a suitable concrete triangle. Is this possible with your comments? If so, please make it a proper solution. Thanks.

Comment: On the one hand, my comments do serve as a road map that will permit you to derive the corresponding Cartesian coordinates.  On the other hand, you are absolutely right that my comments are nowhere close to a clear solution.  Unfortunately, there is a MathSE protocol that prohibits me from doing so, because your question is missing pertinent information.  See [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
 for details.  ...see next comment

Comment: For what it's worth, I strenuously disagree with the protocol in this instance.  In fact, I consider it absurd that you should be required to provide any more information than you already have.  However, MathSE does not belong to me and there is a clear group of *strident* reviewers that I wish to avoid conflict with.  Any other MathSE reviewer is welcome to highjack my analysis and convert it into an *answer*.  Then, the other reviewer can deal with the opposition point of view.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks. I was expecting this to be actually known and was hoping for a citable reference. Cheers.

Comment: I speculate that one reason that no formula has been *published* is because of the problem's ambiguity.  As you indicated, the triangle can be *rotated* as desired, without changing the location of the centroid or the lengths of the triangle's $3$ sides.  Further, even with my premise that the side *below* the centroid is parallel to the $x$-axis, that still begs the question: which of the $3$ sides will be placed *below* the centroid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I see is somewhat inadequate explanation of why you are interested and why you are stuck, but it seems far more likely to me to be someone with a real world problem they lack the mathematical understanding to handle, than a lazy student trying to get someone else to do their homework, so I'll give it a shot. If the drive-by downvoters want to get pissy about it, I don't care.

Since you are after cartesian coordinates, I'll take a more algebraic approach than user2661923. I'll also handle the ambiguity by demanding that $A$ lie on the positive $x$-axis, with $B$ above the axis and $C$ below. If we label the coordinates $A = (x_A, y_A)$, etc. The equation for the centroid is
$(A + B + C)/3 = (0,0)$ which gives
$$x_A + x_B + x_C = 0\\y_A + y_B + y_C = 0$$
But $y_A = 0$ by my condition on $A$, so $y_B + y_C = 0$, or $y_C = -y_B$. And from the $x$ equation, we have $x_C = -(x_A + x_B)$.
Now I get tired of subscripts, so let me relabel the points:
$$A = (a, 0),\quad B = (b, y),\quad C = (-(a+b), -y)$$
Thus we are left with three unknowns $a,b,y$ and the distance equations from them:
$$\begin{align}(b-(-(a+b))^2 + (y - (-y))^2 &= \alpha^2\\
(a-(-(a+b))^2 + y^2 &= \beta^2\\
(a - b)^2 + y^2 &= \gamma^2\end{align}$$
After simplifying,
$$\begin{align}a^2 + 4b^2 + 4ab + 4y^2 &= \alpha^2\\
4a^2 + b^2 + 4ab + y^2 &= \beta^2\\
a^2 + b^2 - 2ab + y^2 &= \gamma^2\end{align}$$
The equations can be multiplied through by constants and added together in various combinations to get rid of the $ab$ terms:
$$\begin{align}3a^2 + 6b^2 + 6y^2 &= \alpha^2 + 2\gamma^2\\
6a^2 + 3b^2 + 3y^2 &= \beta^2 + 2\gamma^2\end{align}$$
Subtracting the first of those two equations from twice the second gives
$$9a^2 = -\alpha^2 + 2\beta^2 + 2\gamma^2\\
a = \frac{\sqrt{-\alpha^2 + 2\beta^2 + 2\gamma^2}}3$$
since $A$ was chosen to be on the positive $x$-axis.

Since $a$ is now a known value, we can take a different course. If we subtract the last two distance equations, we get
$$3a^2 + 6ab = \beta^2 - \gamma^2\\b = \dfrac{\beta^2 - \gamma^2-3a^2}{6a}$$
And $$y = \sqrt{\gamma^2 -(a-b)^2}$$

Comment: Paul, wonderfully clear proof!